# Static variable from namespace is not incremented

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I am implementing quickSort using my own namespace `alg`.

```
namespace alg
{
    static unsigned int comparisons(0);
    void quickSort (std::vector<int>& a);
    int partition (std::vector<int>& b, int leftIndex);
}
```

I need to count comparisons of elements in the array, for that reason I use static variable `comparisons` that GETS incremented in functions but in `main.cpp` it still stays 0.

What is wrong? Why in main.cpp I guess for every `.cpp` file there is a serapate static variable `comparisons`, but I am not sure. Anyway, how can I fix this? Do I actually need to write a class where I can keep a static variable? Or that still won't help?

And Please suggest where can I find detailed information on static variables and namespaces?

**QuickSort.cpp**

```
void alg::quickSort(std::vector<int>& a)
{
....
    comparisons+=1;
}

int alg::partition(std::vector<int>& a, int leftIndex)
{
   comparisons+=a.size()-1;
....
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
alg::quickSort(myvec);
...
std::cout << alg::comparisons << std::endl;
```

Comment: You might want to show the lines changing the variable and using it. Global variable retain their values. BTW, a **much** better approach to count operations it to pass in the comparison function as a function object and have that contain a counter using, e.g., a pointer to a local variable in `main()`: global variables are bad.

Comment: " I guess for every .cpp file there is a serapate static variable comparisons, but I am not sure. Anyway, how can I fix this?". Remove static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A namespace-scope variable declared `static` has internal linkage, which means that *every translation unit (=`.cpp` file) gets its own copy.* So what's likely happening in your case is that the copy in the file implementing `quicksort` and `partition` is incremented, but the one in `main()` is not.

What you need to do is replace the `static` keyword with the `extern` keyword (to make that line just a declaration), and then define the variable in one `.cpp` file (probably the one implementing `quicksort` and `partition`):

```
namespace alg
{
  unsigned int comparisons = 0;
}
```

As for finding more information on this, refer to your favourite [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 2):

> Why in main.cpp I guess for every .cpp file there is a serapate static variable comparisons, but I am not sure

That's right.

Namespace-`static` means it's file-local. This is not the same as class-`static`.

You probably meant to use `extern`.

Comment: Ah yes, this explains the OP's confusion.  The tendency of C++ standards writers to reuse existing keywords has struck another blow!  (They tend to do that because every new keyword breaks existing code: by reusing `static` from C, more C code compiled in C++)